# Do/While loop not looping

Tags: c++, do-while

I am a beginner in C++ and I was doing a do/while loop exercise and I am having trouble with it recognising the condition let alone it not looping properly. Can you guys give me a good foundation on how a simple problem like this is solved? I want to try and use a string to fulfill the condition of the do/while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double mean = 0;
    string continuer;
    do
    {
        cout << "Do you want to proceed?" << endl;
        getline (cin, continuer);
        cout << "something" << endl;
        cin >> mean;
    }
    while (continuer == "Y" || continuer == "y");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish and what is the problem?

Comment: Does getline work with double type?

Comment: @CodingMash I want to create a very simple do while loop where the user just keeps entering a number and then gets asked if they want to continue. Sasha I only assume that it does.

Comment: Doesn't getline include the new line? A simple cout << "'" << continuer << "'" << endl; would tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I gather from your question and comment, you want to iterate through the loop at user's will.

You just want a `char` variable for that, like this.

```
string input ;
int number = 0 ;

do
{
  cout << "Please enter a number" << endl ;
  cin >> number ;
  cout << "If you want to continue, Press Y" << endl ;
  cin >> input ;

} while (input == "Y" || input == "y") ;
```

This do-while loop will execute at least one time, because the condition gets checked at the end of the loop execution. So even if the user does not press Y when asked the first time, this loop would have been executed once. After that, it will go on as long as the condition is fulfilled.

Learn more about the do-while loop here.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a string?

Comment: You have done that correctly in your code above, and I have edited mine for that as well.

Comment: When I execute the code, it prompts do you want to proceed. Whatever I press, it only does the loop once.

Comment: It doesn't work, it keeps looping even while I press the wrong keys.

Comment: Ooo that works now and is simple. Thanks. I guess that getline command is a tad useless at the moment (well not totally).

Answer (score 0):

What do you see? The body of the loop should be executed at least once. Does that happen?

Also, Continuer can be longer than one character, for instance "Y\n". Do test for that.

Here is what I would do:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;



    int main ()
    {
        double number = 0;
        string continuer;
        int loop = 0
        do
        {

            cout << "Do you want to proceed?" << endl;
            getline (cin, number);
            cout << "something" << endl;
            cin>> mean;
            getline (cin, continuer);

            cout << "Your answer was '" << continuer << "'." << endl;
            loop = strcmp("Y", continuer);
            if (loop != 0) strcmp("y", continuer);
            if (loop == 0) cout << "Your choice is to stop." << endl;
            else cout << "Your choice is to continue." << endl;
        } while (loop == 0);
        cout << "Bye" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Be as explicit as you can untill you are confident enough in the language and the algorithm you are working with. It is easier to see what is happening and when it works it is easy to remove the 'cout' lines.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'The body of the loop should be executed at least once.' Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Hayden, what @PapaAtHome says is the lines between `do{` and `}while` will run at least once in any case.

Comment: I tested out the code above and it is saying 'cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'